# Linker searches for file in /usr/lib when it should do in /usr/lib64

Tags: c, linux, gcc, redhat, ld

Trying to link, I get this error:

> /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../libmqic.so when searching for -lmqic
> /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libmqic.so when searching for -lmqic
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmqic

Turns out ld defaults to `/usr/lib` for the mqm library which contains 32bit libs, when it should fetch the 64bit libs in /usr/lib64

Is there any way to configure ld to default to /usr/lib64 so I can keep using -lmqic and not have to hardcode the path?

Comment: It should search there by default (unless you run with -m32) Is there actually a libmqic.so in /usr/lib64/. Also, how does the command line you run look like ?

Comment: Configure `ld.so` in `/etc/ld.so.conf` .... Then use `ldd`  to understand what is really happenning

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch You're not supposed to need to do that. Better to figure out what's really wrong.

Comment: Yes, there are both 32 and 64 versions each in its path and named the same.